# hide QPushButton and QLineEdit Borders

Tags: c++, qt, qstylesheet

i want to hide those borders

[image].

and make it look like this

[image]

I foud that creating a nice GUI with QT is very hard, so i had the idea of designing one as a PNG backround an putting a transparent object on it,so my question is how do I hide the borders of the lineEdits an Buttons in QT

Comment: You can show an image that illustrates what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc i have edited my post you can look now

Comment: Are you using QtWidgets or QtQuick?

Comment: @JonHarper QLineEdit and QPushButton belong to QtWidgets and not QtQuick

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use Qt Style Sheets through the property

```
border-radius: some_value;
```

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString qss = "QWidget{"
                       "background-color: rgb(92, 53, 102);"
                       "}"
                       "QPushButton{"
                       "border-radius: 10px;"
                       "background-color: rgb(85, 87, 83);"
                       "}"
                       "QPushButton:pressed{"
                       " border-radius: 10px;"
                       "background-color: rgb(46, 52, 54);"
                       "}"
                       "QLineEdit {"
                       "border-radius: 10px;"
                       "background-color: rgb(173, 127, 168);"
                       "}";

    a.setStyleSheet(qss);
    QWidget widget;
    widget.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    widget.layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton("button"));
    widget.layout()->addWidget(new QLineEdit);
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image]

References:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html